# ArcGIS 10.2 Changing 'null' to 'zero' in attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, excel

I have a table (Excel, csv) with county names and three additional column headings. I would like to ensure that everything under the three additional headings have a zero rather than a 'null' value.

I do not know Python (I see Python as an answer in other questions).

Comment: The only answers I found involved using Python, which I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did find a solution where I can just change the blank cells in my Excel file to zeroes (http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/772-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-0-or-specific-value.html#a1). I was hoping to not have to go back to Excel though.